# Create document with json in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a cross of several tables in a pyspark view.

[image]

I need to create the following structure.

I'm using pyspark

```
"store": "apple",
    "region": [
        {
            "id": 43211,
            "location": {
                "lat": 3389489,
                "long": 18032
            },
            "country": {
                "name": "USA"
            },
            "city": {
                "name": "New York",
                "region": "uest",
              
            },
            "year ": 2019,
            "nivel": "Médio",
            "slug": "camaro"
        }
    ],
    "sale": {
        "store": 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Flatten the JSON
2. Put the flattened JSON in a list
3. Read list in as a spark dataframe

I would do:

```py
import json

# Correct given JSON to a valid structure
apple_info = (
    """
    {"store": "apple",
        "region": [
            {
                "id": 43211,
                "location": {
                    "lat": 3389489,
                    "long": 18032
                },
                "country": {
                    "name": "USA"
                },
                "city": {
                    "name": "New York",
                    "region": "uest"
                },
                "year ": 2019,
                "nivel": "Médio",
                "slug": "camaro"
            }
        ],
        "sale": {
            "store": 1
        }
    }
    """
)

# Load string as JSON
store_json = json.loads(apple_info)

# Create function to flatten the JSON
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

# Run function on our JSON and put in list
store_flat = [flatten_json(store_json)]

# Read list in as Spark DF
store_df = spark.createDataFrame(store_flat)

# Show spark DF
store_df.show(5)
```

**Output**:

```
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-----+
|region_0_city_name|region_0_city_region|region_0_country_name|region_0_id|region_0_location_lat|region_0_location_long|region_0_nivel|region_0_slug|region_0_year |sale_store|store|
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-----+
|          New York|                uest|                  USA|      43211|              3389489|                 18032|         Médio|       camaro|          2019|         1|apple|
+------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------+-----+
```